# TcpStream blocked on read_to_string

Tags: rust, tcp

### The code

I have a client (`a.rs`) and a server (`b.rs`):

```rust
// a.rs
use std::{
    io::{Read, Write},
    net::TcpListener,
};

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:6400").unwrap();
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
        let mut buf = String::new();
        println!("Waiting for query...");
        stream.read_to_string(&mut buf).unwrap();
        println!("> Received query: {}", buf);

        // Compute something based on query
        let query_res = String::from("42");

        println!("Writing...");
        stream.write(query_res.as_bytes()).unwrap();

        println!("> Done");
    }
}
```

```rust
// b.rs
use std::{io::{Read, Write}, net::TcpStream, thread, time::Duration};

fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:6400").unwrap();

    println!("Sending query...");
    stream
        .write(String::from("What is the best number?").as_bytes())
        .unwrap();
    println!("> Done");

    println!("Receiving...");
    let mut buf = String::new();
    stream.read_to_string(&mut buf).unwrap();
    println!("> Received: {}", buf);
}
```

### What it's supposed to:

Terminal **A**:

```
$ cargo run --bin a
Waiting for query...
```

Terminal **B**:

```
$ cargo run --bin b
Sending query...
> Done
Receiving...
> Received: 42
```

Terminal **A**:

```
> Received query: What is the best number?
Writing...
> Done
```

### Instead, I got:

Terminal **A**:

```
$ cargo run --bin a
Waiting for query...
```

Terminal **B**:

```
$ cargo run --bin b
Sending query...
> Done
Receiving...
```

And both terminals are blocked. Why and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_to_string` reads into String until EOF which will not happen until you close the stream from the writer side.

What you can do it write the query as line using `writeln!`:

```rust
println!("Sending query...");
writeln!(stream, "What is the best number?").unwrap();
println!("> Done");
```

and create a buffered reader to read a line:

```rust
let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
let mut reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
let mut buf = String::new();
println!("Waiting for query...");
reader.read_line(&mut buf).unwrap();
println!("> Received query: {}", buf);
```

Comment: That worked, I guess using a separator is helping. Is it good to use the "\n" separator if I write serialized structs instead of simple strings?

Comment: @Sereyn That depends on how you serialize them. If you use a binary encoding like bincode, newline won't work because there's no guarantee that a newline won't show up in serialized data. But if you use json, then newline is ok because non-prettified json in fact _doesn't_ contain newlines (newlines in strings are encoded as `\n`, two separate octets).