Buffered reader line iterator hangs with no errors
I have a TCP server that tries to replicate a Redis client, which responds to
~ ➤ echo -ne '*1\r\n$4\r\nPING\r\n' | nc localhost 6379                                                                                                                                                                                                          
PONG%   

correctly.
When I do
redis-cli PING

there is no response.
Step by step,

I execute the command.
Line 16, Tokio spawns a task for handling the stream.
Line 38, recv.lines() can be iterated over with no problem.
We start iterating, line is equal to (after each loop)


*1
$4 indicating that next commands length is 4 characters.
PING indicating the command.


Loop is over, and it hangs, with no errors and no response at all? Breakpoint at line 54 match command never gets hit and task suddenly hangs after iterating all lines in loop.
Redis hangs because there is literally no response.
Tokio console shows the task as never yielded (didnt include the tracer code).
CTRL+C redis-cli PING command.
Breakpoint at line 54 gets hit! So it hangs until I SIGSEGV the redis-cli?

??
main file:
mod commands;
use std::{
    io::{BufRead, BufReader, BufWriter, Read, Write},
    net::SocketAddr,
    net::{TcpListener, TcpStream},
};

use commands::{RedisCommand, RedisCommandResponse};

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:6379").unwrap();
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        match stream {
            Ok(mut _stream) => {
                tokio::task::spawn(handle_stream(_stream.try_clone().unwrap()));
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("error: {}", e);
            }
        }
    }
}

async fn handle_stream(_stream: TcpStream) {
    // 0 => type of the input coming in
    // 1 => length of the first parameter
    // 2 => first parameter, command.
    // 3 => length of the second parameter
    // 4 => second paramter, if exists.
    let mut n: u8 = 0;
    let mut command: RedisCommand = RedisCommand::UNKNOWN;
    let mut out: String = String::new();
    let recv = BufReader::new(&_stream);
    let mut deb_buf: String = String::new();
    println!("{}", deb_buf);
    for l in recv.lines() {
        let line: String = match l {
            Ok(line) => line,
            Err(error) => {
                write_string_to_stream(format!("Invalid line: {}", error), _stream);
                return;
            }
        };
        if n == 4 && command == RedisCommand::ECHO {
            out = line.clone();
        }
        if let Ok(_cmd) = RedisCommand::from_str(&line) {
            command = _cmd;
        }
        n += 1;
    }
    match command {
        RedisCommand::UNKNOWN => write_string_to_stream(String::from("Invalid command"), _stream),
        RedisCommand::ECHO => write_string_to_stream(out, _stream),
        RedisCommand::PING => write_string_to_stream(String::from("PONG"), _stream),
    }
}

fn write_string_to_stream(out: String, _stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(&_stream);
    match writer.write_all(out.as_bytes()) {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(_) => {
            _stream.shutdown(std::net::Shutdown::Both);
            return;
        }
    };
}

and the commands:
use std::cmp::PartialEq;
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum RedisCommandError {
    #[error("invalid command")]
    Invalid(),
    #[error("unknown command")]
    Unknown,
}

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub enum RedisResponseCommandError {
    #[error("invalid response command")]
    Invalid(),
    #[error("unknown command")]
    Unknown,
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum RedisCommand {
    UNKNOWN,
    PING,
    ECHO,
}
impl RedisCommand {
    pub fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<RedisCommand, RedisCommandError> {
        match s {
            "PING" => Ok(RedisCommand::PING),
            "ECHO" => Ok(RedisCommand::ECHO),

            _ => Err(RedisCommandError::Invalid()),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub enum RedisCommandResponse {
    PONG,
}
impl RedisCommandResponse {
    pub fn to_string(self) -> String {
        match self {
            RedisCommandResponse::PONG => "+PONG\r\n".to_owned(),
        }
    }
}

only tokio is necessary for cargo.
edit: This also happens if i dont use .lines() and handle the lines myself with read_line directly.
mod commands;
use commands::{RedisCommand, RedisCommandResponse};
use tokio::io::{AsyncBufReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, BufReader, BufWriter};
use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:6379").await?;
    loop {
        let (socket, _) = listener.accept().await?;
        tokio::task::spawn(handle_stream(socket));
    }
}

async fn handle_stream(mut _stream: TcpStream) {
    // 0 => type of the input coming in
    // 1 => length of the first parameter
    // 2 => first parameter, command.
    // 3 => length of the second parameter
    // 4 => second paramter, if exists.
    let mut n: u8 = 0;
    let mut command: RedisCommand = RedisCommand::UNKNOWN;
    let mut out: String = String::new();
    let mut sock = BufReader::new(_stream);
    let mut line = String::new();
    loop {
        line.clear();
        match sock.read_line(&mut line).await {
            Ok(bfsize) => {
                if bfsize == 0 {
                    break;
                } else {
                    let current = line.clone().trim().to_string();
                    if n == 4 && command == RedisCommand::ECHO {
                        out = current.clone();
                    }
                    if let Ok(_cmd) = RedisCommand::from_str(&current) {
                        command = _cmd;
                    }
                    n += 1;
                }
            }
            Err(error) => {
                write_string_to_stream(format!("Invalid line: {}", error), &mut sock).await;
                return;
            }
        };
    }
    match command {
        RedisCommand::UNKNOWN => write_string_to_stream(String::from("Invalid "), &mut sock).await,
        RedisCommand::ECHO => write_string_to_stream(String::from(out), &mut sock).await,
        RedisCommand::PING => write_string_to_stream(String::from("PONG"), &mut sock).await,
    }
}

async fn write_string_to_stream(out: String, sock: &mut BufReader<TcpStream>) {
    if let Err(_) = sock.write_all(out.as_bytes()).await {
        sock.shutdown().await.ok();
    }
}

it just hangs up.
thanks for any help
<3

I meant hanging, not returning. oopsie.


The iterator returned from this function will yield instances of [io::Result]. Each string returned will not have a newline byte (the 0xA byte) or CRLF (0xD, 0xA bytes) at the end


It may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69482188/tcpstream-blocked-on-read-to-string

Seems like not related, or I couldnt understand nothing. sorry :(

Nit: Ctrl-C is SIGTERM, not SIGSEV

It's the same issue as the duplicate: for l in recv.lines() will keep waiting for new lines until the client closes the connection, but redis-cli doesn't so your server keeps waiting because it has no way to know that the client won't eventually send a new line. You need to either process the command from inside the loop or to break from the loop once you have a command.
